# Was there some special "badge" awarding moment tonight?

Tags: support, tag-badges

Logged in today, and saw this:

[image: pic-with-6-badges-earned]

Note: no upvotes today, but 6 badges earned?

Comment: Oprah moment: *You will  all get a badge!!!*